# Try to read a pcap file, yield and &block explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pcap

i dont understand how to use this method from pcap_simple(https://github.com/ryanbreed/pcap_simple/blob/master/lib/pcap_simple.rb) gem, what is &block?

```
def each(&block)
  file.seek(PCAP_HEADER_LEN)
  loop do
    header_data=file.read(PACKET_HEADER_LEN)
    break if (header_data.nil? || header_data.length < PACKET_HEADER_LEN)
    header=PcapRecord.new(header_data)
    raw=file.read(header.incl_len)
    break if (raw.nil? || raw.length < header.incl_len)
    packet=Packet.new(:raw_data=>raw,:header=>header)

    yield packet unless packet.datagram.nil?
  end
end
```

and "yield packet", i know packet is a class but how it work with yield??

I tried something like this but nothing, the fist line work I could open the file.

```
    @archivo = PcapSimple::PcapFile.new("file_name","/home/deniel/Sites Ruby on Rails/h2/out.pcap") 

@archivo.each() do

logger.info "HELLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLO!"

end
```

Sorry and Thanks! im new in ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work copy-paste the gem method directly on my class like this way.

```
  @file=File.open("/home/deniel/Sites Ruby on Rails/h2/out2.pcap","r")
  @header=PcapHeader.new(@file.read((5*32 + 2*16)/8))

   @file.seek((5*32 + 2*16)/8) 
   loop do
   header_data = @file.read((5*32 + 2*16)/8)    
    break if (header_data.nil? || header_data.length < ((4*32)/8) )
   header=PcapRecord.new(header_data)
   raw=@file.read(header.incl_len)
    break if (raw.nil? || raw.length < header.incl_len)
   packet=Packet.new(:raw_data=>raw,:header=>header)
   logger.info packet.src
   end
```

So... I still dont know what is the

> yield packet unless packet.datagram.nil?

and if i leave that line, appears this error:

```
LocalJumpError in WelcomeController#index

no block given
```